# Empty table by using NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT g.name, s.hour, gs.weekday
FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN group_schedule gs ON gs.schedule_id = s.id
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.id = gs.group_id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM group_schedule
  WHERE group_id =6
)
ORDER BY g.name, gs.weekday
```

that return:

```
name    hour        weekday
A1-A2   10:00:00    1
A1-A2   17:00:00    1
A1-A2   10:30:00    1
A1-A2   17:30:00    1
A1-A2   18:00:00    2
A1-A2   11:30:00    2
A1-A2   18:30:00    2
A1-A2   11:00:00    2
A1-A2   12:30:00    3
```

But I need too to get rows which don't have these combinations, for example:

```
name   hour      weekday
A1-A2  10:30:00  1
A1-A2  11:00:00  1
A1-A2  11:30:00  1
...
```

If I use NOT EXISTS I obtain an empty table.

Comment: Is it just me or is the only where-clause in your initial query group_id=6 and I don't know what "don't have these combinations" mean?

Comment: So you schedules that don't belong to group 6?

Comment: Your `exists` clause doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You're probably better off if you [edit] your question to provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but do you mean something like:

```
SELECT g.name, s.hour, gs.weekday
FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN group_schedule gs 
ON gs.schedule_id = s.id AND group_id = 6 
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.id = gs.group_id
ORDER BY g.name, gs.weekday
```

Moving the group_id condition out of the general WHERE clause and into the group_schedule JOIN?  You know can have an arbitrary logical expression following the ON keyword.

Comment: its probably `group_id <> 6` but then typically people would write `Where  gs.group_id <> 6`

Comment: Many Thanks! Finnaly, I had to move out the group_id condition, as ciritcalfix means and use <> operator as Conrad Frix also said.          `SELECT s.id, s.hour, gs.weekday
FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN group_schedule gs ON gs.schedule_id = s.id
AND group_id <>6
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.id = gs.group_id
WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM group_schedule
)
ORDER BY gs.weekday, s.hour
LIMIT 0 , 30`